# Issue with Combine array php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to combine two arrays in one array,  i want to get value and need to keep it has a key for second array.

**`example`**

```
Array (
     [CONFIRMATION_NUM] => DBSUUA
      )
```

**

```
here my code 
first array
```

**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => CONFIRMATION_NUM
    [1] => BOOKING_AGENT
    [2] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [3] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [4] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [5] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [6] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [7] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [8] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [9] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [10] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [11] => BOOKING_AGENT
    [12] => CONFIRMATION_NUM
 )
```

second array is

```
Array (
 [0] => DBSUUA 
 [1] => faras-nmdc 
 [2] => UKAZZQ 
 [3] => yco-lmcy 
 [4] => QVTUTS 
 [5] => sohail-npcc 
 [6] => HGQQEF 
 [7] => masood-muss 
 [8] => HOHCFQ 
 [9] => yco-lmcy 
 [10] => JSDUIT 
 [11] => otacallcentre 
 [12] => LHLHWL
)
```

I tried with this code in this code $tablecolumnsarray is first array and $tabledatacsvcolumnarray is the second array name

```
$keys = array_keys($tablecolumnsarray);
                    $final=array();

                    foreach ($tabledatacsvcolumnarray as $v) {
                      $final[]=array_combine($keys,$v);
                    }

                    print_r($final);
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed example of how your expected output would be.

Comment: I got it i tried with other code it works has expected thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it is enough to use: `$final = array_combine($tablecolumnsarray, $tabledatacsvcolumnarray);` to achieve what you want.

But the reason that you're only getting two keys this way is the first array. Take a look at its values:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [1] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [2] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [3] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [4] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [5] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [6] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [7] => BOOKING_AGENT 
    [8] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
    [9] => BOOKING_AGENT 
   [10] => CONFIRMATION_NUM 
   [11] => BOOKING_AGENT 
   [12] => CONFIRMATION_NUM
)
```

There cannot be two keys with the same name in the array. But there are only two different values in that array so the final array will contain only two (probably last) elements.

Comment: isn't possible to get all?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something that you're not showing, no need to loop:

```
$final = array_combine($tablecolumnsarray, $tabledatacsvcolumnarray);
```

If `$tabledatacsvcolumnarray` is actually multidimensional then:

```
foreach($tabledatacsvcolumnarray as $values) {
    $final[] = array_combine($tablecolumnsarray, $values);
}
```

Comment: HI i tried this but it showing like this [code] Array ( [CONFIRMATION_NUM] => CGDSAC [BOOKING_AGENT] => otacallcentre )[/code] only one is showing

Comment: Then your sample arrays are incorrect.  I updated with a guess.

Comment: No array  is correct i am getting with that details

Answer (score 0):

```
$final = array();
foreach ($tablecolumnarray as $n=>$column) {
  $final[$column][] = $tabledatacsvcolumnarray[$n] ;
}
print_r($final) ;
```

Comment: HI Chris o tried this but it showing like this <code> Array ( [CONFIRMATION_NUM] => CGDSAC [BOOKING_AGENT] => otacallcentre )</code> only one is showing

Comment: Edited to add `[]`, creating a sub-array. You need to be clearer in what you're expecting so see.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$final = array();
foreach ($tablecolumnsarray as $k => $column) {
  $final[$column] = $tabledatacsvcolumnarray[$k] ;
}
print_r($final) ;
```